# display pdf as stream in webbrowser control

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, webbrowser-control, windows

In my windows application, I want to read a pdf file and using byte[] I want to convert it into a text file.

I am able to do this but while displaying the content of text file in webbrowser control it is displaying some encoded data.

How can I display the actual data in pdf. Below is my code

Convert pdf to text file

```
byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(OpenPdfDialog.FileName);
string byteString = Encoding.Default.GetString(bytes);
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(@"E:\file.txt", byteString );
```

Displaying content to webbrowser control

```
 byte[] bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\path.txt");
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(bytes2);
 ms.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
 ms.Position = 0;
 webBrowser1.DocumentStream = ms;
```

OR

Reading the file as stream and displaying the stream in the webbrowser control also displaying the encoded data

```
FileStream to_strem = new FileStream(OpenPdfDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open);
webBrowser1.DocumentStream = to_strem ;
```

Ultimately I want to display the pdf's content into webbrowser control without loading the pdf file.

Comment: You're not converting the PDF file to text anywhere. You're reinterpreting the PDF bytes as text using the default encoding, which is **not** going to produce anything sensible.

Comment: Can you tell me how to convert PDF file to text

Comment: There are several libraries that let you extract text from PDF files.

Comment: I dont want to extract only text, I want to convert pdf to content into string and create encrypted text file from it.

Comment: Then encrypt the PDF first, and convert that to base64. Don't just cast the bytes to a string, the result won't be valid text.

Comment: This also results in some random string